# "You must be logged in" error in WS Play Framework (scala)

Tags: scala, playframework

I am getting an error that looks like:

```
{"error":"You must be logged in to complete this action"} 
{"error":"You must be logged in to complete this action"}
```

even though, supposedly, I already authenticated as can be seen in the code below. My code looks:

```
val baseURL = “https://www.dummywebsitename.org”
val authenticationPath = “/ajaxauth/login”
val queryPath = “/basicdomaindata/query/class/tle/ABC/CDE”
val loginURL = baseURL+authenticationPath
val queryURL = baseURL+queryPath
```

Below, I create a cookie, then perform the request with authentication and then finally try to get the data from a remote RESTful service.

```
val cookie = DefaultWSCookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", None, None, Some((2*60*60).toLong), true, true)

val wsRequest = ws.url(loginURL).withAuth(userName, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).addCookies(cookie).get()

val wsDataRequest = ws.url(queryURL).post(file)
```

When I run the code, I get the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about that but you probably should use cookies directly from wsRequest using [WSResponse.cookies](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WSResponse.html#cookies:Seq[play.api.libs.ws.WSCookie]) method.

```scala
//Not tested. Don't have prepared env :(
val reqLogin = ws.url(loginURL)
  .withAuth(userName, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
  .addCookies(cookie)
  .get()

val wsDataRequest = reqLogin
.filter(_.status == 200)
.flatMap { loginRes => 
//even if we are in Success() branch of Future here, it doesn't mean
//request was made well. It means only we have touched server successfully.
//We still need to check if login was success and so on.
// to see what login result relly is println or check below values:
//loginRes.statusText 
//loginRes.status 
//loginRes.body

  ws.url(queryURL)
    .withCookies(loginRes.cookies :_*)
    .post(file)
}
```

Comment: Looks very promising, Scalway. Thank you! At the line that reads ".withCookies(loginRes...", I am now getting the following error:

```
Error:(234, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[play.api.libs.ws.WSCookie] (in scala.collection) 
 required: Seq[play.api.libs.ws.WSCookie] (in scala.collection.immutable) 
      .withCookies(loginRes.cookies :_*)
```

Comment: Though, .toSeq after loginRes.cookies seems to have solved that problem. Still getting the "{"error":"You must be logged in to complete this action"}" error message though.

Comment: I've commented in code. I assume it is service problem, but don't know. Hope it will help. If so up-vote please and mark as answered :).

Comment: Definitely upvoted, but I am still bit of a newbie for my vote to count (4 points away!). :)

Thanks again. Yea, not sure what is going on. I do get OK for statusText, 200 for status but {"Login":"Untried"} for body. :/

Comment: you can also check what kind of cookies/requests you have while using browser/curl.

Comment: OK, thanks. After further research, it might be an XSS issue. Looking into it at the moment. Thanks again.